# Comparing nullptr QVariant against empty QString gives different output in Qt5.9 and Qt5.12

Tags: c++, qt

This program gives different outputs when I change Qt version:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVariant>

int main()
{
    QVariant value("");
    qDebug() << value;
    bool whatValue = QVariant::fromValue(nullptr) == value;
    qDebug() << "*** value Check ***" << whatValue;
}
```

- In Qt 5.9 with C++11, output is:

  ```
  QVariant(QString, "")
  *** value Check *** false
  ```
- In Qt 5.12 with C++17, output is:

  ```
  QVariant(QString, "")
  *** value Check *** true
  ```

Why do I get different results?

Comment: What does this print for your `QVariant`s in each case: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#typeName ? Also, check what this gives while you are at it: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#isValid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing `QVariant`'s can be tricky, especially if their meta-types differ, because a conversion between them is always attempted. In your latter case comparison returns true because Qt 5.12 supports conversion of a `QMetaType::Nullptr` to `QString`, see [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.12.6/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.cpp), lines 511-513.

Since this case is missing in Qt 5.9, conversion fails and comparison returns false, consequently.

If you're not happy with this behavior, you can enforce meta-type checking in a function of your own, like:

```
bool compareVariants(const QVariant & x, const QVariant & y)
{
    if(x.type() == y.type())
    {
        return (x == y);
    }
    return false;
}
```

i.e. fall back to `QVariant::operator==` for same meta-type only, return `false` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation